# Error: (-13:Image step is wrong) Step must be a multiple of esz1 in function 'cv::Mat::Mat'

Tags: java, opencv, matrix, matrix-multiplication, mat

I'm currently working on a piece of code that is supposed to do a Matrix Multiplication of two matrices [3x4]*[4x1] in order to obtain a [3x1] Matrix. To do so I am using Java and OpenCV since I'm working in the context of image processing.

Here's a simplified piece of code that I used :

```
Mat projectionMat = new Mat(3,4,CvType.CV_32FC1);
Mat pointI = new Mat(1,4,CvType.CV_32FC1);
Mat transPointI = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC1);
Core.transpose(pointI, transPointI);
Mat sUV = new Mat(3,1,CvType.CV_32FC1);
```

I'm gonna spare you how I fill the matrixes but when I dump (print) them after the fill here's what I obtain on the terminal :
[projectionMatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrPzQ.png) and [transPointI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DKNm.png)

So I do have my [3x4] and [4x1] matrixes, next step is the Matrix Multiplication that I try to achieve using the openCv Core.gemm funciton as shown below -the sUV matrix is the destination Matrix- :

```
Core.gemm(projectionMat, transPointI, 1, new Mat(), 0, sUV);
```

From what I understang everything should be working here, but when I execute the code eclipse throws an error pointing at the Core.gemm line :

```
Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.10) C:\build\3_4_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:607:
error: (-13:Image step is wrong) Step must be a multiple of esz1 in function 'cv::Mat::Mat']
at org.opencv.core.Core.gemm_1(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Core.gemm(Core.java:3702)
```

I've looked around a little and I can't seem to stumble across anyone who met the same problem. Even when Image step errors occur they are ususally not caused by the Core.gemm function. Anyway I'm kinda lost so any solution/hint to a solution would be more than welcome, thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok turns out I find the answer to my question ! It was actually a matter of type conflicts, all my matrices were instanciated to contain floats, which was ok until the last multiplication since it results in doubles. So I just had to change my matrices to contain doubles. To do so what I changed is :

```
Mat projectionMat = new Mat(3,4,CvType.CV_64F);
Mat pointI = new Mat(1,4,CvType.CV_64F);
Mat transPointI = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_64F);
Core.transpose(pointI, transPointI);
Mat sUV = new Mat(3,1,CvType.CV_64F);
```

After that the multiplication was executed successfuly !